# android toolbar with fragments

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar

I have toolbar and framelayout(for fragments) in my main activity layout. I have to show the toolbar in every fragments. But the issue is each fragment has different background image that is dynamically changing. Toolbar menu icon is used for navigation drawer open and close operation. How I will handle these issue?

Comment: which background you are referring to?? fragment or toolbar??

Comment: I guess its exactly same scenario which i have faced recently.  Needed much clarification.

So you have a navigation drawer , and want that navigation drawer to be on all the fragments and these fragments are replaced from navigation drawer menu .

And the toolbar style depends based on the fragment but the menu items in toolbar are same .

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @manikanta: Yes this is the same scenario I was looking for. Can you please help me for a solution ?

Comment: Okay A big code block a head try to bear with it...

Answer (score 1):

Before posting the code block let's first understand what are we are going to do.

1.Create a HomeActivity that holds all the fragments.

Here is the `activity_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the `app_bar_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

the other xmls of navigationview -- `activity_home_drawer.xml` contains navigation drawer contents and  `nav_header_home.xml` is the navigation drawer header layout.

2.Let's come to java part of the `HomeActivity.java`

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private HomeBean bean;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        initListener();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        //this menu contains all the common menu item actions
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

//common options bar item click here i have notifications icon common for all the fragments
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_notifications:
                AppUtils.launchActivity(HomeActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class,intentData);
                return false;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_dashboard:
                    //you can cache this fragment in case of repeated creations
                    selectedFragment = new DashBoardFragment();
                }

                break;

        }

        if(selectedFragment != null){
            displayFragment(selectedFragment);
            DrawerLayout drawer = ButterKnife.findById(this,R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void displayFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        if(fragment !=null){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initToolBar() {}

    public void setToolbar(Toolbar toolbar){
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setActionBarToggle(toolbar);
    }



    private void setActionBarToggle(Toolbar toolbar) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void initListener() {
        NavigationView navigationView = ButterKnife.findById(this,R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        //as the first item is show by default
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Now as an example let see how the fragments are written.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings,container,false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        return  view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).setToolbar(toolbar);

    }
}
```

Corresponding fragment xml   `fragment_settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="Fragment Name">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/notification_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/settings"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_settings" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the corresponding xml `content_settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/min_widget_padding"
        android:id="@+id/nsv_settings_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

// your content goes here
</<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I hope this gives clear picture on how to do in case if you have any other doubts please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. I helped

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);// To enable actionbar in fragments
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
//Here it is necessary to connect the layout menu
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment2, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }
 }
```